# How to add images in a loop with gm montage function?

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I want to combine several images in a grid. How can I accomplish the following without knowing the image paths beforehand?

```
gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
    .montage('/path/to/second_image.jpg')
    .montage('/path/to/third_image.jpg')
    .geometry('+100+150')
    .write('/path/to/montage.png', function(err) {
        if(!err) console.log("Written montage image.");
    });
```

Lets say the image pathes are available in an array:

```
paths=['/path/to/image.jpg', '/path/to/second_image.jpg', '/path/to/third_image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hm. I did not use much that module, i d do,

```
var g = gm('/path/to/image.jpg');
paths.forEach(function(p){
    g.montage(p);
});
g.geometry('+100+150')
.write('/path/to/montage.png', function(err) {
    if(!err) console.log("Written montage image.");
});
```

no ?

Comment: thanks that works! You just had a little typo: function() --> function(p)